# MacOS Create a Process in suspended state

Tags: c++, objective-c, linux, macos

**Use-case**

1. Create a new process ( running an arbitrary application ) in suspended mode ( using eg. exec )
2. Process created ( MachO loaded ) but no single line of code executed
3. Do some stuff w/ the suspended process memory
4. Resume the process

On windows, once can use CreateProcess in conjunction with the "CREATE_SUSPENDED" to achieve the above mentioned.

**Is there a "CREATE_SUSPENDED" C++/Obj-C equivalent for MacOS ???**
( NSTask created in suspended mode is an equivalent of what I am looking for )

Comment: What are you trying to do with the subprocess's memory?

Comment: Inject specialized code

Comment: Oh that's a good question. I don't know off the top of my head how to do it directly, but you might look in to how the processCreate() function from Dyninst works. You might find [Dyninst](http://www.dyninst.org/manuals/dyninstAPI) generally useful for your purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`posix_spawn()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/posix_spawn.2.html) with a spawn attribute of [`POSIX_SPAWN_START_SUSPENDED`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/posix_spawnattr_setflags.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/posix_spawnattr_setflags).

It's a bit of a pain to use but will do what you want, however I am unsure how you can access the memory of the child process.